# Load Data Local Infile with password_hash

Tags: php, mysql, password-hash

I am trying to upload CSV to a table. However, the passwords are in plain text which i would like convert to password_hash in the process.  Please help.

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$mylfile."'
   INTO TABLE parentstudent
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
   IGNORE 1 LINES 
   (parentstudent_id, @parent_id, student_id, school_id)
   set parent_id =".password_hash."'(parent_id,".PASSWORD_DEFAULT.")";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","confapp");

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: One option would be to read in the CSV file hash the passwords, write a second CSV file with the hashed passwords then do the `LOAD DATA ...` stuff.

Comment: Can you please give me an example...I am new to php

Comment: Sure, can you give me one line of the CSV file as an example to go on? Of course replace any sensitive values with dummy data.

Comment: id(autoincremtent) parent_id(password_hash Student_id School_id
NULL 44444444 425450 0236
NULL 11111111 425450 0237
NULL 22222222 425450 0238

Comment: and `parent_id` is the thing that needs to get hashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a file called `clearpwords.csv` with contents like this:

```
1,test,1,1
2,testtest,2,1
```

The following program will hash the second column.

```
<?php
// this is needed for any significant number of inputs to password_hash()
set_time_limit(0);

$infile = "clearpwords.csv";
$myfile = "hashedpwords.csv";

$reader = fopen($infile, 'r');
$writer = fopen($myfile, 'w');
$buffer = '';

while ($line = fgetcsv($reader)) {
    $line[1] = password_hash($line[1], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $buffer .= implode(',', $line) . "\n";

    if (strlen($buffer) > 1024) {
        fwrite($writer, $buffer);
        $buffer = '';
    }
}

fwrite($writer, $buffer);
fclose($reader);
fclose($writer);
```

It will create a file called `myfile.csv` that looks like this.

```
1,$2y$10$KwG1S4w7T4ov71bFSsKhlOW2CpFrMurtZRz3az94o7BX70pmohCb.,1,1
2,$2y$10$zQkH5vDIYLCqkUxxaqH6nuZ67fXj71XiBVjxztvst.dtvSlFqjDou,2,1
```

You can now run your script on `myfile.csv`

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$mylfile."'
        INTO TABLE parentstudent
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (parentstudent_id, @parent_id, student_id, school_id)";

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "confapp");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Note that [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is only available in PHP 5.5 and above. If you are running a version prior to this and upgrading is not an option use the [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function instead.

Don't be tempted to use `SHA-*` or `MD-*`.

Comment: worked perfectly without the most important piece "$data[1] = password_hash($data[1], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);"            with the password_hash function, it times out before the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" what can i do to rectify that problem? Thanks!

Comment: What does the log file say? How big is the CSV file?

Comment: the file size is 115kb the file has 3268 rows but only writes 1600 rows to the hashedpwors.csv and stoped..No error messages, just timed out.  If i remove the password_hash, it worked.  My guess is the password_hash is  slowing down the process, consequently, exceeding the wait_timeout...

Comment: That was my thought as well. This hash function is deliberately designed to be slow, making it a suitable choice for password hashing. Try changing the max_execution time to 0.

Comment: Thanks robmj! it works, but it took 8 minutes to upload 7000 records...and i have 20k records to upload....

Comment: That is just the price you have to pay for a strong cryptographic hash function.